# fetch timestamp mysql value in $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, timestamp

```
$qry = "SELECT user, TIME_FORMAT(last_login_time, '%H:%i') FROM login_attempts WHERE user = '".$username."'";
$result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);
if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0){
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO login_attempts(userid, user, attempts, last_login_time) VALUES('', '$username', '{$_SESSION['count']}', '{$_SESSION['login_time']}')");           
}
else{                   
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['login_time'] = $row["last_login_time"];
    mysql_query ("UPDATE login_attempts SET attempts = '" .$_SESSION['count']."' WHERE user = '".$username."'");            
}
```

In the above code I'm storing my `$_SESSION['login_time']` value in '`login_attempts`' table where the column name is 'last_login_time'.

Now I need to fetch this value and store it back in `$_SESSION['login_time']` array so that I get to know when the last time user tried to enter. How shall I fetch this value???

The datatype of `'last_login_time'` column is `'timestamp'.`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias your `TIME_FORMAT` column in order to reference it.

```
SELECT user, TIME_FORMAT(last_login_time, '%H:%i') AS last_login_time ...
```

Also, why not `UPDATE` the login attempts to `SET attempts = attempts + 1` ?